# Change array variable names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of JSON data I am using. Each array item is a blog category, but in the JSON it is presented as the category id#. With the code below, I'm not sure how to set a new array that essentially converts the category id# to the category name. I would have to set what each id# is supposed to be named.

```
const ButtonCategories = (productCategories, setCategory) => {
  return (
    productCategories.map(category => (
      <button
      key={category}
      className={`filter-button btn-${category}`}
      onClick={() => setCategory(category)}
    >
      {category}
    </button>
  )));
}
```

Comment: Could you share a sample json data

Answer (score 1):

You could store a category id mapping in a variable as below,

```
const categoryMapping = {
  id1: "Category 1 Name",
  id2: "Category 2 Name",
  id3: "Category 3 Name"
}
```

and the array, you can map like this,

```
const transformedBlogs = blogs.map(blog => {
    return {
      ...blog,
      id: categoryMapping[blog.id]
    };
  });
```